# Spaces between words in menu not working. Must remove space between words to make submenu work

Tags: html, menu, submenu

My index file has a menu item I want named "What We Do", but the only way to get the sub-menus to appear is to remove the spaces and write "WhatWeDo"

How do I get it to allow multiple word menu items?

I have to write

HOME

```
   <li class='menu-item-has-children'>
        <a>WHATWEDO</a>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
```

in order to make the sub-menus to appear.

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not support whitespace characters. If you want to obtain a space, you need to use `&nbsp`.

```
<li class='menu-item-has-children'>
  <a>WHAT&nbspWE&nbspDO</a>
<ul class='sub-menu'>
```

Comment: Do you mean `&nbsp;` ?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you can create nested lists using the `<ul>` (unordered list) and `<ol>` (ordered list) elements for creating lists and the `<li>` (list item) element to define individual list items. By nesting these elements, you can create lists within lists. Here's how to create a nested list in HTML:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">What We Do</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```